# Why is Boolean's size in vba 2 Bytes?

Tags: vba, types, range

In my apprenticeship we started doing now vba at school. When our teacher handed us out the data type summary, I was kind of confused.
.....

> Boolean -> 2 Bytes -> Range: True / False

Well `True` / `False` is of course plausible but, Why are 2 Bytes used, as Booleans hast just to be able, to represent any of 2 values?
I mean theoretical we could use a single Bit for representing any value of this range.
(But I know thats senseless, as we are using Highlevel-Languages)

As I asked my teacher this, he appeared as he had never asked him self the same, and after a few seconds of cogitation,
he just finished this with an answer of the kind "You have to accept it, as it is, what it is."
But I wouldn't call my self a good programmer, if I were just 'using', and would never be interested in understanding.
So I'm asking now here:

Is there any reason in vba, why `Boolean` needs 2 Bytes instead of a single Byte?

Comment: because you use 0 for false and non-one for true. In a implicit conversion of expressions to boolean you evaluate more than 1 bit and more than 1 data type (incl. Integer, Long, etc)

Comment: @user2140173 So? 0000 0000 0000 0000 = False, any 0000 0000 0000 0001 = True (or 1000 0001 0010 1011 what you like more). For why there is 2 bytes?

Comment: Wondered the same, especially since there is a `Byte` data type that only uses one byte for values 0-255. It doesn't check out why it would internally use anything larger.

Answer (score 1):

For backwards compatibility with the original `Microsoft BASIC`.

`Microsoft BASIC` only had 3 types:

- `Integer` (16-Bit)
- `Single` (32-Bit)
- `String`
- (...and Arrays of the above types)

The `Boolean` data type didn't exist in `Microsoft BASIC` and only existed internally (as part of expressions).

```
10 INPUT "Do you want more stars? "; A$
20 IF LEN(A$) = 0 THEN GOTO 90
```

I'd speculate therefore that originally `Boolean` was created internally as an `Integer`. Later when upgraded to 32-bit, `Boolean` remained at 16-bit for backward compatibility. And I'd doubt `Byte` existed until `Visual Basic`. However that's all speculation.